# How to add an event in a mail open with Thunderbird directly to a calendar of Lightning?

Tags: email, thunderbird

I receive mail from CapitaineTrain with an event.
I've got the "This email contains an invitation" but I cannot click to add it on my calendar.

Do you know how I can do that?

Comment: Does the message show an 'accept' button or no? I think the logic is you have to accept first, then it will be put into calendar.

Comment: In my case it is not an invitation.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the mail content then select `Convert > Event`

Comment: But it is not good enough.